# Can new glibc versions be used with an old kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, compatibility, glibc

Apparently glibc can be compiled with `--enable-kernel` to support older kernel versions. However, I haven't been able to find information on *what kernel versions are supported on a particular glibc version*. Ideally, I want to see a compatibility matrix for every glibc (2.x) and kernel (2.6.x) releases. Does it exist?

If it doesn't exist, perhaps it's because every glibc versions (in the last 5 years or so) supports all kernels since 2.6.0?

(Arch = x86-64, if that matters)

Answer (score 24):

For some versions of `glibc`, the announcement email says which kernel versions are compatible.

```
glibc    Released      Requires Linux kernel version
----------------------------------------------------------

2.34     1 Aug 2021    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.33     1 Feb 2021    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.32     5 Aug 2020    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.31     1 Feb 2020    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.30     1 Aug 2019    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.29     1 Feb 2019    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.28     1 Aug 2018    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.27     2 Feb 2018    ?   (same as 2.26?)
2.26     2 Aug 2017    3.2 (or higher)
2.25     5 Feb 2017    ?   (same as 2.24?)

2.24     4 Aug 2016    on i[4567]86 and x86_64  ->  2.6.32
2.24     4 Aug 2016    on other platforms       ->  3.2

Note 1:  Some minor architectures require a higher kernel version than
         listed above.

Note 2:  Your Linux distribution may vary from the above, as Glibc can
         optionally be configured at compile time to require a kernel
         version newer than the oldest supported version.
```

It may be possible to extend the above table by tracking down and reading more of the announcement emails for older (or newer) versions of `glibc`.

For reference:

```
Linux distribution    glibc version    Requires Linux kernel version

Debian 11 Bullseye    2.31             3.2 ?
Debian 10 Buster      2.28             3.2 ?
Debian 9 Stretch      2.24 on x86      2.6.32
Debian 9 Stretch      2.24 on other    3.2

Ubuntu 20.04          2.31             3.2
Ubuntu 18.04          2.27             3.2
Ubuntu 17.10          2.26             3.2
Ubuntu 17.04          2.24             ? 
Ubuntu 16.10          2.24             ?
Ubuntu 16.04          2.23             ?
```

Sources:
[The GNU C Library Release Timeline](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline)
[The GNU C Library (glibc)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html)
[The GNU C Library version 2.27 is now available](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-announce/2018/msg00000.html)
[The GNU C Library version 2.26 is now available](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-08/msg00010.html)
[The GNU C Library version 2.25 is now available](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-02/msg00079.html)
[The GNU C Library version 2.24 is now available](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-08/msg00212.html)
[DistroWatch.com: Ubuntu](http://distrowatch.org/table.php?distribution=ubuntu)
[Ubuntu glibc `MIN_KERNEL_SUPPORTED`](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/ubuntu/+source/glibc/tree/debian/sysdeps/linux.mk?h=ubuntu/2.31-0ubuntu9.1&id=3ec7fb93788b07e5227a00f04556f3ef89447fe2#n4)

Comment: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline

Answer (score 6):

You can check in in the sources. General dependency is defined in [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/configure.ac](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/configure#l54) and currently (in master branch, before 2.32 release) is: 3.2.0

There are some architecture specific dependencies, search for `arch_minimum_kernel` in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/[arch]/configure`, e.g. in the current master branch (before 2.32 release):

- [aarch64](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/configure#l4): 3.7.0
- [csky](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/csky/configure#l3): 4.20.0
- [ia64](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ia64/configure#l8): 3.2.18
- [mips](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mips/configure#l475): 4.5.0
- [nios2](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nios2/configure#l4): 3.19.0
- [powerpc64](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/powerpc/powerpc64/configure#l225): 3.10.0
- [riscv](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/riscv/configure#l4): 4.15.0
- [x32](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/x32/configure#l4): 3.4.0

Although this is not 100% correct, see RISC-V change in [NEWS](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=NEWS): [64-bit RISC-V requires a minimum kernel headers version of 5.0](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=f1bb5499d12e0175ca69cb72e7e7471fd02457b8).

Comment: Most useful answer for me

Answer (score 5):

According to the project's [README](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/trunk/libc/README?rev=10032&view=markup) you can use glibc 2.4 with kernels older than 2.6, but you will lose some functionality:

> When working with Linux kernels, the GNU C Library version 2.4 is
> intended primarily for use with Linux kernel version 2.6.0 and later.
> We only support using the NPTL implementation of pthreads, which is now
> the default configuration.  Most of the C library will continue to work
> on older Linux kernels and many programs will not require a 2.6 kernel
> to run correctly.  However, pthreads and related functionality will not
> work at all on old kernels and we do not recommend using glibc 2.4 with
> any Linux kernel prior to 2.6.

Note that `--enable-kernel=VERSION` means:

> compile for compatibility with kernel not older than VERSION

Comment: Nice answer, but nowadays outdated.